# sub string search bash scripting

Tags: string, bash, match

When given a string I want to search for a substring which matches two characters (9&0. 0 should be the last character in that substring) and exactly two characters in between them

```
string="asd20 92x0x 72x0 YX92s0 0xx0 92x0x"
#I want to select substring YX92s0 from that above string

for var in $string
do
if [[ "$var" == *9**0 ]]; then
    echo $var  // Should print YX92s0 only
fi
done
```

Obviously this above command doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You match each element against the pattern `*9??0`. There are several ways you can do this; here's one that uses the string to set the positional parameters in a subshell, then iterates over them in a for loop:

```
( set -- $string
  for elt; do [[ $elt == *9??0 ]] && { echo "found"; exit; }; done )
```

Comment: Sorry I missed to add for loop in my original question. There was one actually. My question was about the search pattern. When I changed my pattern *9**0 to *9??0 that if condition worked just fine :). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
string="asd20 92x0x 72x0 X92s0 0xx0"

if [[ $string =~ [[:space:]].?9.{2}0[[:space:]] ]]; then
    echo "found"
fi
```

Or better, taking advantage of *word spliting* :

```
string="asd20 92x0x 72x0 X92s0 0xx0"

for s in $string; do
    if [[ $s =~ (.*9.{2}0) ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} found"
    fi
done
```

This is regex with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).

Comment: This solution didn't work on string "X9xx0 9xx0x". It returned 9xx0x instead of X9xx0

Comment: copy/paste one more time, post edited accordingly. I've made the assumtion that there's only one character or nothing between the leading space and the 9 digit

Comment: IMO the second solution would need a $-anchor.

Comment: I was using a for loop like your second solution.. that regex didn't work on "x9xx0 9xx0x". It selected 9xx0x instead of wanted x9xx0

Comment: for s in $string; do if [[ $s == *9??0 ]]; then echo $s; fi done  WORKED FINE :)